# Golang app gets stuck but unstucks somehow when trying to terminate it

Tags: go

I have written a golang web application using standard go libraries. I have an API that starts a goroutine.

In the goroutine I loop through a finite list of data, around 5000 units, and process each entry. As each entry is processed I print to terminal using `fmt.Println()` and sleep using `time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)`. Each processing takes roughly 500ms.

I start my go program using Ubuntu in Windows (Windows Subsystem for Linux), with command like `go build && ./app`.

When I kick off the goroutine through API call, I can see prints in the terminal. After a while I notice the print messages stopping and nothing being processed. I check the DB using `SELECT COUNT(*)...`, as I log one DB entry per processing and see the count does not change. When I go to terminate the program by pressing <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> in the terminal, the program doesn't terminate. Instead somehow the processing resumes and I start to see prints in the terminal again.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Or how I can start to debug this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could we see some of your code please to help with the debugging?

Comment: maybe you are stuck into some computations that are bound to a context which itself is cancelled at ctrl-c. who knows without source code ?